# How to return an XML file from a function with a node?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a simple XML

```
<bds>
<bd>
    <id>10</id>
    <user>john</user>
    <servers>
        <name>pc24</name> 
    </servers>
</bd>
<bd>
    <id>12</id>
    <user>peter</user>
    <servers>
        <name>pc25</name> 
    </servers>
</bd>
```

I have a function and I would like it to return an XML file with all the elements that hang from a node.

```
$collection = "bds"
$attribute = "name"
$obj = "pc25"


function test () {

    if ($xml.SelectNodes("//$attribute").name -eq "name") {
    

        return $xml.SelectNodes("//$attribute").parentnode | Where $attribute -eq $obj
    
    }

    else {
    
        return $false

    }
}
```

I would like the output of the function will be:

```
        <id>12</id>
        <user>peter</user>
        <servers>
            <name>pc25</name> 
        </servers>
```

How can I generate an XML file with the return of the function?

Comment: The output is not XML. There is no top node. The input is also not XML, the </bds> tag is missing.

Comment: What is your PowerShell version? Why tag this with all `PowerShell` tags you could find?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a slightly smarter XPath to select your nodes, and then the `InnerXml` property to get the output string you're after:

```bsh
PS> $xml = [xml] @"
<bds>
  <bd>
    <id>10</id>
    <user>john</user>
    <servers>
      <name>pc24</name>
    </servers>
  </bd>
  <bd>
    <id>12</id>
    <user>peter</user>
    <servers>
      <name>pc25</name>
    </servers>
  </bd>
</bds>
"@

PS> $xml.SelectNodes("bds/bd[servers/name = 'pc25']").InnerXml
<id>12</id><user>peter</user><servers><name>pc25</name></servers>
```

Note - `bds/bd[servers/name = 'pc25']` means "find all the `bds/bd` nodes that have a child `servers/name` node with a value `pc25`".

You can then retro-fit this back into your function using your variable values in the XPath string as appropriate...